# Google Chat API: Deploying Webhook integrations & Bots

Tags: google-workspace, google-chat

It looks like Google has released some updates to its Chat API which allow a few new methods for deploying & managing Google Chat spaces and members. You can see the new documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces/create

My org uses a lot of chat spaces for monitoring and alerting, and I would love to be able to create spaces routinely as part of a pipeline/deployment. Using the API, is it possible to  create a webhook and/or bot connection in a programmatic fashion? To properly automate my orgs chat spaces, we would need to be able to add this integrations and apps as well. I do not see any articles / references saying yea or nay. If the answer is no, has google released any sort of feature calendar clarifying (if) the feature is on the map for them?

Also, does anyone know if there is a terraform (or alternative IaC solution) release in Google Chat APIs future? Would make deployments significantly easier. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using the API, is it possible to create a webhook and/or bot connection in a programmatic fashion?**

Answer: No, it is impossible for right now. But there is a feature request for [creating incoming webhooks](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207768443). But there is no ETA about the completing date.

If the mentioned feature aligns with your preferences, feel free to engage with the issue link by providing feedback. Alternatively, if the feature isn't what you're looking for, you can create a new issue by clicking [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:350158&s=created_time:desc).